# erroneous pipeline: no element "x264enc"

Tags: windows, gstreamer, x264, libx264

I have a gstreamer command that requires x264enc and the error I get is:

> WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "x264enc"

I saw posts that the solution is to install gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly, but I need to launch the command in Windows while I was managed to find the plugin only for [Linux](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-plugins-ugly.html).

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select "Full installation" when installing from the official released binaries. the plugin should get installed then. Or what what was your installation source?